# Unit sshd.service not found

Tags: ssh

Good morning to all,
I've a problem with ssh. I'm using Ubuntu 23.10, new installation. I've installed openssh-server via

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

However, when I try to use something related to sshd, e.g.

```
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

or

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

I've the following error:

```
Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found
```

or

```
Failed to restart sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found
```

I've tried to purge openssh several times and in different ways:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-server
sudo apt purge openssh-server
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt remove ssh --purge -y
```

and I've tried different ways to reinstall:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo apt install ssh -y
```

But I've failed every time. The file in \etc\ssh\sshd_config is correctly installed.

What can be the problem? How can I solve it?
Thanks in advice for your help

EDIT

This is the file list according to

```
dpkg -L openssh-server
```

[file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMX61.png)

Comment: According to `dpkg -L openssh-server`, what files do you actually have installed from the package?

Comment: I've added the file list in the post

Comment: Are you using Linode?

Answer (score 3):

Use given command to restart the ssh service

```
systemctl restart ssh
```

As per my knowledge sshd is for Centos, Not for Ubuntu

Comment: In ubuntu 16 sshd worked, they might change something since then.

Comment: Though the ssh is the client not the server service